# GET data from ajax and put it into sql query at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

How grab data when user press submit at searhing form(when he's chosen figure's width and long) PHP dont see width or long var. Do ajax and put ajax vars into sql query at same time. User`s not logged in, guest.

```
... 
function figure(position) {
var width = parseInt(position.width);
var long = parseInt(position.long);
$.ajax({
    url: 'figures.php',
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    data:       {
        width:  width,
        long: long
    },
    success:    function(data) {
        //
    }
});
}
```

PHP

```
 ...
 public function getneededfigures() {
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $long = $_GET['long'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM figures WHERE  width='$width' AND long='$long' 
 .. }
 ...
```

Comment: The easiest way with your code would be to use `url: 'figures.php?width=foo&long=bar'`. Something bad should also be said about referencing the `$_GET` superglobal within a function...

Comment: thx Alex! I appretiate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the JS as recommended by AlexP:

```
function figure(position) {
    var width = parseInt(position.width);
    var long = parseInt(position.long);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'figures.php?width=' + width + '&long=' + long,
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        data:       {
            width:  width,
            long: long
        },
        success:    function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
}
```

A better practice is to pass the variables as parameters, and NOT to reference $_GET or $_POST directly.  What happens if those values aren't in the query string?  What if you want to manuall call the function independent of an HTTP request?

```
$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : false;
$long = isset($_GET['long']) ? $_GET['long'] : false;
function getneededfigures($width, $long) {
    if ( $width && $long ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM figures WHERE  width = '".some_function_to_sanitize_data($width)."' AND long = '".some_function_to_sanitize_data($long)."'";
        ...do stuff...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that you also need to sanitize user inputs before sending them to the database to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: thx! I`ll sanitize! Think about better way to pass vars...Not exacatly works now, but you've given me all minds which i need)